# Summing and plotting by month and arbitrary attribute in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently getting into data analysis and am building a little accounting app to keep track of my expenses.

My goal is to track my expenses in a Django app, make some analyses with Pandas on it and visualize it with Matplotlib.

My data basis comes from a Django ORM query like this:

```
qs = MyExpenses.objects.values('date', 'amount', 'category')
```

Then I use Pandas' `from_records` method to create an indexed DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(qs, index='date', coerce_float=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)  # manually make index a proper DateTimeIndex, datetime.date objects don't seem to be converted automatically
```

Checking the DataFrame's content with `df.head()`:

```
            amount  category
date        
2017-12-29  14.90   Food
2017-12-27  2.98    Household
2017-12-27  9.72    Food
2017-12-24  2.00    Food
2017-12-23  1.49    Household
```

Looking good so far.

At this point I don't know how to correctly proceed. **I want to have my expenses summed up per category per month.**

This groupby operation:

```
summed_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1M'), 'category']).sum()
```

Returns the correctly aggregated data:

```
                                amount
date        category    
2016-02-29  Cosmetics           2.45
            Food                376.41
            Household           43.82
            Leisure             630.13
2016-03-31  Food                345.41
            Household           14.76
            Leisure             553.35
...
```

But calling `summed_df.plot()` renders this plot:
[image]

Obviously Panda uses the combined index of date and category as the x axis and the amount column as a single data series. As stated above, that's not what I want.

Consequentially I have to do summing in another way or somehow remove category from the index and make it a regular column again, but I have no idea how to approach this.

Can some of the Pandas cracks out there help me out?

Comment: What kind of plot are you looking for? Can you describe what your ideal plot looks like?

Comment: You should have a look at other questions, e.g. [this recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852607/how-to-plot-multiple-line-charts-from-a-pandas-data-frames) has a [mcve] and a clear description of the desired output, such that it can be answered. Also make clear in how far other questions do not help you solve your problem.

Comment: Desired output is a line chart with the x axis being the time, y axis being the summed amount spent and one series for each category. Sorry If that didn't become clear by my initial post.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

Consider pivoting your groupby result where each category becomes their own column to be individual lines. Below demonstrates with random data (seeded for reproducibility):

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epoch_time = int(time.time())

np.random.seed(55)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(np.random.randint(1450000000, epoch_time)) 
                                for _ in range(500)],
                   'category': ["".join(np.random.choice(['Cosmetics', 'Food', 'Household', 'Leisure'],1)) 
                                 for _ in range(500)],
                   'amount': abs(np.random.randn(500))*100}).set_index('date')

print(df.head(10))
#                          amount   category
# date                                      
# 2016-12-23 10:30:18   10.711083  Household
# 2016-05-05 15:40:07  176.670986  Cosmetics
# 2017-04-24 17:55:04   16.700308  Cosmetics
# 2018-01-02 06:41:33  242.877311       Food
# 2017-12-15 00:06:29   95.990759  Household
# 2016-07-30 18:22:13   45.610068       Food
# 2016-07-13 16:00:11   60.704399    Leisure
# 2017-04-15 20:28:03   12.410939       Food
# 2017-12-07 19:33:18   61.599076  Cosmetics
# 2017-10-29 20:20:07  117.341928    Leisure
```

**Groupby and Plot**

```
summed_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1M'), 'category']).sum()\
                .reset_index().pivot(index='date', columns='category', values='amount')

summed_df.plot()
```

[image: Plot Output]